# Naming Convention for Firebase Platform Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, naming-conventions

**Question:**
Beside this [piece of documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data) Firebase has on Realtime Database, is there any other documentation available?
Is there a set of preferred naming conventions for Firebase Realtime Database entities such as databases, and field names?

**For instance:**

- Database uses the word in singular and end with the “db” suffix.
- They are lower case.
- Document fields for instance camelCase, userName,
  firstName, lastName, et cetera.

I looked online and here (*StackOverflow*) but I could not find much beside the one already mentioned. Any external links will be helpful.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The Firebase Database infers no meaning to how node names are spelled, beyond disallowing certain characters as outlined in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#how_data_is_structured_its_a_json_tree).

The Firebase team typically names nodes on collection level as plural (e.g. `users`, `posts`, `items`) and individual properties as singular (e.g. `name`, `title`, `price`). But this is a matter of preference, and does not influence how the database functions.